# xaml(wpf) How to address a control from my customwindow template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a customwindow template by redefining it, and inheriting from window. This template resides in a separate class library, and i build a dll and reference it from my main project.
This is a part of code from custom window xaml:

```
        <!-- Window style -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
            <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="moveRectangle" Fill="#24282A"
                                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="WindowName" Background="#24282A" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#24282A">
                                        <Button x:Name="minimizeButton" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Content="0" />
                                        <Button x:Name="restoreButton" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Content="1" />
                                        <Button x:Name="closeButton" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Content="r" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Grid Background="#24282A" Opacity="0.9"
                                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,0,5,5">
                                        <AdornerDecorator>
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </AdornerDecorator>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="resizeGrid">
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Height="5"
                                    x:Name="top"
                                    Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    x:Name="bottom"
                                    Height="5"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                    Width="5"
                                    x:Name="left"/>
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                    Width="5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    x:Name="right" />
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Width="5"
                                    Height="5"
                                    x:Name="bottomLeft" />
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Height="5"
                                    Width="5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    x:Name="bottomRight" />
                                                        <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Width="5"
                                    Height="5"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    x:Name="topRight" />
                                                    <Rectangle
                                    Stroke="{x:Null}"
                                    Fill="#24282A"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Width="6"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Height="5"
                                    x:Name="topLeft" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

As you can see, there is a label called "WindowName". i want this label to be kind of Title bar in my custom window, and i wanna call it's property content from my main wpf application which inherits from this custom window. Everything works ok, except i have no idea how i should call this label to set it's content. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to bind the content of that `Label` to the `Title` property of the base `Window` class since the base class already has a dependency property that you can just reuse. All you will need to do is update the xaml for you label component as below:

```
<Label x:Name="WindowName" Content={TemplateBinding Title} Background="#24282A" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

You could also override `OnApplyTemplate` in your `CustomWindow` and use a method like `FindName` to get the `Label` using its name and then updating it through a direct reference, but the binding way is much cleaner so I wouldn't consider that route although I wanted to at least mention it.

Comment: Thx, it helped me :) It's what i wanted. May i ask you about some kind of warning,  
'CustomWindow.Title' hides inherited member 'Window.Title'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   
Is it better to add new?

Comment: Good point. Window already has a Title dependency property so you don't need to go to the trouble of creating a new one (assuming you are only ever going to want to use a string for the title). I will update my answer, all you need to do is make the update to the xaml.